# MutationObserver override newest mutation

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I'm trying to wait till a Mutation event kicks to override the value it just received. Before I was trying to apply it normally, but then it kept being overriden by the other value that is given from the 3rd party I can't control.

```
/** Intercept changes in select2-drop positioning **/
var MutationObserver = window.WebKitMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log("Override existent new found top value with -> " + newHeight);
        $(".select2-drop-active").css({'top':newHeight+"px"});
    });    
});
```

After I try this code, I think it enters in a loop cause my Chrome freezes and the memory starts increasing rapidly

Is there a way to stop the continous calls in Mutations ?

Comment: A simple way could be to test if `top` has not already the `newHeight` value before setting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pause your mutation observer at any time by calling [observer.disconnect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#disconnect())

So, depending on your use case, you might do something like this:

```
var MutationObserver = window.WebKitMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log("Override existent new found top value with -> " + newHeight);
        $(".select2-drop-active").css({'top':newHeight+"px"});
    });
    observer.disconnect();
    console.log('pausing the observer');
    // If needed for your use case, start observing in 1 second
    setTimeout(() => observer.observe(), 1000);
});
```

Comment: Yes! I do need it, I just need to stop the continuous calls.